# Data about drugs/medicine and outcomes

Tags: data-request, medical, disease, covid19

I'm am looking for some datasets that contain data about a specific disease - any disease (preferably with several known treatments). I need such datasets, that contain information about the patients, the treatment/medicine that they received, and the treatment's outcome. I've tried to look everywhere, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: where have you looked? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

[ClinicalTrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/) contains lots of information - not just for the US, but also for the other  markets  important to "Big Pharma".

The blog of drug discovery chemist and blogger Derek Howe [In the Pipeline](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/) (it's now a column of *Science* magazine) contains in-depth discussions of interesting recent discoveries. Each of his [blogposts about clinical trials](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/category/clinical-trials) contains  numerous links to papers and, if you dig deeper, data.

If you want a somewhat standardized access to datasets from experiments, get familiar with the Bioconductor Project that was developed by the R community. Example: [> 80 Human cancer datasets](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/BiocViews.html#___CancerData)

(Bioconductor specifies how code and data should be packaged together, to encourage  data sharing and improve reproducibility).